# JavaFX layout algorithms

Tags: java, javafx, minecraft

I am working on simplified (partial/basic) rewrite of JavaFX structure into Minecraft in order to simplify and unify GUI creation.

I am approaching this on MUCH smaller scale, losing a lot of features, but trying to preserve general idea of how layouts are handled internally.
Node structure with children and general tree-like structure in present, as well as all events, properties like min, pref, max width/height, Insets and Parent structures like BorderPanes, GridPanes, etc.

While I am trying to understand (or actually find in src) all relevant code regarding handling "spreading" nodes in 2D space (spreading as in handling mentioned min/pref/max size properties of Nodes to build whole GUI), I thought maybe someone here would be able to point me into right direction and maybe even explain some of internal operations.

As far as I can tell - algorithms behind all this seem to be not so simple (heuristic and stuff), but note that I don't want nor need very advanced ideas, just an outline or where to look for one - as for now I am trying to design kind of multiple-pass recursive algorithm to discover and wrap/resize nodes to fit in scene but it becomes very complicated once you enter unusual property values (as in checkking every possible case).

Comment: See [*Customize Your Application Layout*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-nov/o60javafx-170536.html).

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but if you dig deeply into Javafx stuff, like copying/refactoring their existing classes for GUI handling (skins, behaviours...) you will notice that a lot of their code uses functions that will be deleted in next JDK versions and that a lot of things that you would like to take control of are private or package private. Thus, I recommend to not waste your time on this. I'm making a program which needs to override some of private Javafx algorithms and I'm having a pain in the butt remaking it.